# Automatically Compile .Net UserControls

Tags: vb.net, svn, visual-studio-2008

I would like a means of making VB.Net projects automatically compile, possibly on load.
Background:

- Several projects at work use `UserControl`s.
- I am the only one currently using SVN, with the repositories being file-based on my desktop.
- I have been adding `bin` to the `svn:ignore`, as each run would change the files.

Unfortunately, when I update the copy of the project on a network share, my coworker has to rebuild the project; otherwise, the Visual Studio designer complains about missing classes.

As such, is there a way to make Visual Studio automatically compile the project on load?  Or would my best bet be to set up a TortoiseSVN post-update script?

Comment: Add your Visual Studio version as a tag.  Also, get everyone on version control!  Collaborating on code that lives on a network share is just *begging* for problems!

Comment: @PatrickQuirk For a current project, we're using VS2008 because of the Oracle tools; normally we use VS2013.  And believe me, I've tried.